# Date Format issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a file like this in my SharePoint site

```
ActiveLitHoldWithOneDrive-3-27-2022.csv
```

I'm trying to get the file using PowerShell like this

```
$Global:CurDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$Global:OneDriveListURL = "/sites/msteams/Shared%20Documents/OneDriveInventory/ActiveLitHoldWithOneDrive-"+$Global:CurDate+".csv"
```

The file existed in my SharePoint but some reason I'm getting this error so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion

```
Error Downloading File! Exception calling "OpenBinaryDirect" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
```

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the date?

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon , yes it work if I hardcoded like this 

$Global:OneDriveListURL = "/sites/msteams/Shared%20Documents/OneDriveInventory/ActiveLitHoldWithOneDrive-3-27-2022.csv"

Comment: Are you sure `$Global:CurDate` is giving you the date you expect it to be?

Comment: I think so because If I print out just $Global:CurDate then it print out exactly like this 03-27-2022

Comment: ooo probably because of the 0 infront of the 03

Comment: Well you have an extra `0` there if we compare with your harcoded link, so the format you might be looking for is `[datetime]::Today.ToString('M-d-yyyy')`

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. really appreciate it